# SuperUser vs Serverfault Question Counts

Tags: discussion

Not really a question, but I thought it would interest people here:

SuperUser right now as 33,777 question, while ServerFault has 33,734.  They are amazingly within 43 questions of each other.  I think SuperUser actually passed ServerFault (which launched earlier) some time within the last couple hours.

In other news, StackOverflow looks to surpass the 600,000 mark this week.

Comment: Nice. What's the average questions/day on each of the sites? Obviously it's higher on SuperUser but it would be interesting to see by how much.

Comment: Something I have always been interested in seeing is the percentage of answers accepted between the two sites.  Is there any way of getting that data?

Comment: Still lagging behind Stack Overflow though...

Comment: SuperUser and ServerFault are dropping even further behind StackOverflow, combining to less than 10% of the questions on StackOverflow.  That's probably less than the number of admin questions that are asked on StackOverflow, despite those questions being off topic there.  Sounds to me like an argument for merging ServerFault and SuperUser.

Comment: @WarrenDew: Merging Super User and Server Fault would be a sure way to drive away the best contributors at SF... no self-respecting sysadmin wants to look a bunch of helpdesk questions.

Comment: @Aarobot that's what tag filters are for

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: No, that's exactly what tag filters *aren't* for. Trying to pound in nails with a glass bottle again. Can you think of a single non-meta-tag that would somehow cover *all* of the helpdesk questions? Tag filters are meant for categorizing topics under the same general umbrella, not as an excuse for merging two unrelated sites for political reasons (traffic). Just because two different things have to do with "computers" doesn't mean they belong in the same Q&A - otherwise you might as well merge them all with Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure in part because of the sheer volume of questions that we send over to SU.

Answer (score 1):

Super User *ought* to have more questions on account of having a much wider audience, considering that there are so many more... er, *users*, than administrators and other IT professionals.  And by the same token there are going to be more helpful folks who can answer those questions.

It wouldn't surprise me if Super User surpasses Stack Overflow someday... but SO has a pretty big head start, so it might be a while!

Comment: Not gonna happen. A "user" is not a "super user". There are way more programmers than super users.

Comment: @Pacerier If it happens, it will be a result of questions sent from StackOverflow.